# setting left margin in \itemize

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to use `\itemize` to list several short paragraphs of prose designated (a),(b), (c) etc. The first line of each paragraph should be indented as usual, then the rest of the paragraph should be flush with the left margin. But when I use `\itemize`, the entire paragraph is indented a bit. I don't want that. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Now that I reread the question, you seem to need a numerated list with alphabetical labels and not an `itemize`; you can do this easily with `enumitem`, defining a dedicated `enumerate`-like list with the desired settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myprose}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myprose,1]{
  leftmargin=0pt,
  label=(\alph*),
  align=left,
  itemindent=\dimexpr\parindent+\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}

\begin{document}

Test text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example
\begin{myprose}
\item First item and some additional test text for the example and some additional test text for the example and some additional test text for the example and some additional test text for the example
\item Second item and some additional test text for the example and some additional test text for the example and some additional test text for the example and some additional test text for the example
\end{myprose}
Test text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example text for the example

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo Medina, You're a good man, many thanks. Just what I wanted. Thanks also to others who told me things I might have known, but didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps one of  these two layouts?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
A
\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text .text text text text text text text text text.

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), wide=0pt, labelindent=\parindent]
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}

More text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text.

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), wide=0pt, labelindent=\parindent, nosep]
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}

Still more text still more text still more text still more text still more text still more text still more text still more text still more text still more text still more text still more text.
\end{document}
```

[image]